# Last Visit Date Override

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, language, date

I am trying to override the Last Visit Date in the admin area of my Joomla 3.4.1 site.

I have manually made overrides to the following constants (site and admin)

[image]

and

[image]

it's not making any difference to the Last Visit Date, it's still i the following format.

[image]

I have cleared the cache and logged in/out numerous times. The dates seem to have effected other parts of the site, just not the part I want!

I would then also like to display this info one the site front end when a user is logged in, my curreny code I am using is below;

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if (!$user->guest) {
echo "<h3>Hi {$user->name}</h3>";
echo "<p>You were last here on {$user->lastvisitDate}.</p>";
}
?>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this for that Saxum IP Logger component or a different extension?

Comment: No the standard Joomla user manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're referring to has not been implemented for the **Last Visit Date** in the Joomla User Manager.

If you open the following file and go to line **152**:

> administrator\components\com_users\views\users\tmpl\default.php

you will see the following:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('date', $item->lastvisitDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

You can create a Template Override for this file and format it however you like.

You could either change the format there and then, or use one of Joomla's pre-defined formats, for example:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('date', $item->lastvisitDate, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC4')); ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @johnny_s - Assuming you're using the default Isis admin template, you would create your override in `administrator\templates\isis\html`. Same process as a frontend template override, but it goes in your admin template folder instead

Comment: @johnny_s - Replace `$user->lastvisitDate` with `JHtml::_('date', $item->lastvisitDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`.....Inside you can change `Y-m-d H:i:s` to the format of your choice ;)