# How to reformat a date string?

Tags: joomla-3.x, date, format

I'm trying to enter the date in tags default_items.php (in an override) to see the date in tags list.

I am using `<?php echo $item->displayDate; ?>` and this prints: **2018-08-04 06:04:37**, but I'm trying to format the date as **4 Aug 2018**.

I tried the code below to change the format and display:

```
<?php
$mydate = $item->displayDate;
echo $mydate->format('j M Y');
?>
```

but this generates an error:

> Call to a member function format() on string

How can I change the date to the new format?

Comment: Other relevant links: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/10603/12352 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/36256751/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456048/2943403 , https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JHtml::date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$mydate = $item->displayDate;` simply refers to the date string, therefore `$mydate` is not an object and you cannot `format()` it.

You'll need to pass the date string through `JHtmlDate` like so:

```
echo JHtml::_('date', $item->displayDate, 'j M Y');
```